# Can I change the enchantment on my gloves in Candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I feel like sometimes, I chose the wrong enchantment on my items so I think maybe I can change it. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the enchantment, but after your first enchant, the merchant starts selling gloves so you can have both sets of gloves with enchantments.